# Сортировка массива php без учёта "ёлочек"

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый, но давно бьюсь над такой проблемой, которую эстетично и просто решить не получается (а городки городить не хочется, сердце подсказывает, что есть лёгкий и изящный способ решения).

В общем, есть ассоциативный массив php, среди значений данного массива есть такие, которые начинаются с кавычек "ёлочек", то есть - вот такого символа '«'.

Внимание, вопрос: как сделать сортировку, чтобы данный символ при сортировке не учитывался, а то получается, что все значения, которые начинаются с него уходят вверх, что противоестественно.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Удалить этот символ?

Comment: Хочется его всё же сохранить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Функция [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php). Вполне себе выход из положения: наименьший огород, который вы сможете нагородить.

2) Чуть более велосипедный способ - если вам не нужны ключи, можно в ключи запихнуть значения без елочек, а потом воспользоваться [ksort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ksort.php) - сортировкой по ключам.

UPD:
3) во всяких каталогах от вездесущего "the" спасаются, запихнув его в конец.
Делаем функцию "запихивания" и "восстановления".
Первая будет преобразовывать в 'значение«»', вторая - в '«значение»', между ними - сортировка.

USORT:

```
function my_anti_furtree_compare($a, $b){
    $a = trim($a," ,.'«»");
    $b = trim($b," ,.'«»");
    //с учетом регистра
    //return strcasecmp();
    return strcmp($a,$b);
}
usort($my_furtree_arr,'my_anti_furtree_compare');
```

Или как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать :)

Comment: Вот вариант с usort весьма заинтересовал, но знаний не хватает чтобы им воспользоваться(

Comment: ЛовитеЧЕТЫРЕСИМВОЛА

Comment: Только не `trim`, а `ltrim`, ведь Гургену надо отбросить символы в начале строки.

Comment: Спасибо! Прямо то что требуется!

Comment: @Zhukov_Roman, ну, по-идее, да. Но trim мне привычнее.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообще, конечно лучше такого не допускать. Либо не сортировать, либо хранить однотипные в этом плане элементы. Встроенной функцией сортировки тут не обойтись, так или иначе придется городить огород. Аля писать кастомную функцию, которая будет тримать кавычки, после чего уже сортировать :)

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать.

Comment: Вот как раз пользовательская сортировка с удалением кавычек мне кажется самым красивым решением.

Comment: Согласен. Проблема обычная, пользовательская функция сортировки вполне спасет. Никаких огородов. Если только не допускается очень большой массив. Если так, тогда да — нужно хранить строки_для_сортировки отдельно от «значений».

Answer (score -1):

Набросал вот:

```
$arr = array(
    '#medved',
    'gys',
    'olen',
    '#krab',
    'abrikos'
);

var_dump(gsort($arr));

function gsort($arr) {
    $arr_copy = $arr;

    $arr = array_map(function($val) {
        if(!preg_match('/\w/', $val[0])) {
            return substr($val, 1); // Удаляем первый символ, если это не буква
        }
        return $val;
    }, $arr);

    asort($arr);

    for($i=0, $narr = array(), $keys = array_keys($arr); $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        $narr[] = $arr_copy[$keys[$i]];
    }

    return $narr;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то ваш код ошибку выдал, но всё равно спасибо за желание помочь!

Comment: @Гурген проверьте, работает ли модуль php.